# Synchronize N-processes in strict order with Semaphores

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, semaphore

I'm facing simple issue with Semaphore's task.

I am having N-processes (P1, P2, P3, P4...Pn). No matter in what order I create threads, I need them to execute in exact order (P1, P2, P3, P4...Pn). I need to come with solution, where I use minimum semaphores required.

It would be quite simple using Mutex, but the task says "use only semaphores".

I'm using only one semaphore. In while, within the condition, if order number is NOT equals your ID number, just unlock semaphore and cycle in while, till order number is equals to your ID number.

I think that problem might be with "Spurious wakeups".

**Here is my code:**

```
sem_t semvar;
int order = 0;

void *sayHello(void *thread_id){
    int *my_id = (int *) thread_id;

    while(1)
    {
        // take semaphore and close critical zone to read order variable to recognize who's on turn!
        sem_wait(&semvar);
            if(*my_id == order)
            {
                // if I'm on turn, then I shout my number and set order variable to someone behind me
                printf("I'm thread no.: %d\n", *my_id);
                order++;
                break;
            }
        // release semaphore if I'm not on turn!
        sem_post(&semvar);
    }
    // release semaphore if it was my turn, I shout my number and gonna end (die)!
    sem_post(&semvar);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int numbOfThreads = 13;
    int *thread_id[numbOfThreads];
    int new_thread, i;

    pthread_t threads[numbOfThreads];


    // generating thread numbers --> NOTE: you need this, if you use random thread generating!!!
    for(i = 0; i < numbOfThreads; i++)
    {
        thread_id[i] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
        *thread_id[i] = i;
    }

    // random thread generating for testing to make sure it works
    pthread_create(&threads[10], NULL, sayHello, (void *) thread_id[10]);
    pthread_create(&threads[12], NULL, sayHello, (void *) thread_id[12]);
    pthread_create(&threads[8], NULL, sayHello, (void *) thread_id[8]);
    pthread_create(&threads[3], NULL, sayHello, (void *) thread_id[3]);
    pthread_create(&threads[5], NULL, sayHello, (void *) thread_id[5]);
    pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, sayHello, (void *) thread_id[1]);
    pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, sayHello, (void *) thread_id[0]);
    pthread_create(&threads[4], NULL, sayHello, (void *) thread_id[4]);
    pthread_create(&threads[7], NULL, sayHello, (void *) thread_id[7]);
    pthread_create(&threads[6], NULL, sayHello, (void *) thread_id[6]);
    pthread_create(&threads[2], NULL, sayHello, (void *) thread_id[2]);
    pthread_create(&threads[9], NULL, sayHello, (void *) thread_id[9]);
    pthread_create(&threads[11], NULL, sayHello, (void *) thread_id[11]);

/*
    // automatic thread generating
    for(i = 0; i < numbOfThreads; i++)
    {
        thread_id[i] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
        *thread_id[i] = i;
        new_thread = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, sayHello, (void *) thread_id[i]);

        if(new_thread)
        {
            printf("Error has occured");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
*/

    // do not end main function before all the threads are done with work!
    for(i = 0; i < numbOfThreads; i++)
    {
        pthread_join( threads[i], NULL);
    }
    printf("All the threads are gone!");

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I'm *guessing* that this is [tag:c], but I shouldn't *have* to guess. Please [edit] your question and add a suitable language tag. Also, hopefully you're aware that this is a terrible use case for threads. If you have multiple tasks that have to run strictly one at a time and in order, that's a use case for a *single* thread to perform all of those tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Yes, it is C. I'll update tags (btw: thanks for that). 

Well I know that it is not parallel but serial execution, but that's what the task says. The main goal is, that P2 will not execute before P1 ends. P3 will not execute before P2 ends etc... I think you get the point. And of course I'm looking for best solution not to have N-semaphores for N-processes.

Comment: You probably ought to have some form of sleep in your loop to give other threads a chance versus the thread that won the race for the semaphore, realised it wasn't it's turn, released it and then raced around the loop again to try to grab the semaphore.

Comment: "It would be quite simple using Mutex" - Then why not just use a semaphore to 'emulate' a mutex?

Comment: To handle spurious wakeup, check the value returned by sem_wait(), if it is not zero, do a continue in the loop to do another sem_wait(). The issue with using a single semaphore is that the program could get stuck looping in a single thread. See if you can figure out a way to avoid this by using two semaphores.

Comment: 'It would be quite simple using Mutex' - would it?  How would a mutex help?

Comment: Use n semaphores.  Don't mess about.  It IS the best solution.

Comment: @rcgldr only OS/semaphores that are faulty have spurious wakeups.

Comment: The sysem overhead of creating/maintaining a semaphore for each thread is negligible compared with that of creating the thread in the first place. There is no issue with the obvious solution.

Comment: @MartinJames - "If the semaphore value is currently zero, then the calling thread will not return from the call to sem_wait() until it either locks the semaphore or the call is *interrupted by a signal*"   [sem_wait](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0216/6m6ngupmq/index.html). In the case of Windows, spurious wakeups are not an issue if using Windows native semaphores, WaitForSingleObject(), WaitForMultipleObjects(), ... . As for the OP's assignment, two semaphores should be enough, although not the most efficient.

Comment: @rcgldr there is only one OS I kow of where the OS primitives like semaphores are broken, (and question is not tagged linux:).  All the others have semaphores that work as Dijkstra defined.  Anyway, as you say, the other methods described require polling, and so suck:)  Anyway, it's obviously an assignment with unreasonable serialization and constraints, so I'm not sure if it's useful to future users/visitors.   I'm not going to downvote it, but it's kinda 'offish'.

Comment: @MartinJames - The OP is using sem_post() and sem_wait(), which I assume are the typical non-native interfaces added to pthreads or posix. Polling is not needed if using two semaphores (spurious wakeups require looping, but that's not cpu bound polling). I could explain a two semaphore approach, but I assume this is part of this assignment.

Comment: I have one question for you. If you need to order the thread like P3, P5, P4, P0, P1,P9,P2,P7,P6 how will you do that? The way you are doing this not correct implementation.

Comment: One more question, you are saying that you need to use just one semaphore and not n numbers. But I can see in your code you are using only one semaphore and not n. I can help you with a sample program with semaphore and conditional variable to order the execution of thread in any order is that fine for you?

Comment: Ok, I see some misunderstandins in here. By "It would be quite simple using Mutex" i mean that mutex and condition variables are quite easier to implement to solve this problem. But that is not the question. The task is to have n-threads, no matter how I create them, always the thread with number 1 is executed first, then thread number 2, etc...

Comment: @PatrickStar - as mentioned in my prior comment, the assignment cannot be properly done using one semaphore, but it can be properly done using two semaphores. See if you can figure this out. If you're still stuck, I can explain later.

Comment: @rcgldr i have already solve it that day later, but appreciate your support. thanks

Comment: @PatrickStar - how did you solve it, other's here may want to know. What I was going to suggest is using a second semaphore for all the threads that are out of turn, so that eventually only the in turn thread is waiting for the first semaphore. I can explain the details later if anyone is interested.

Comment: @rcgldr I used 2 semaphores. First one is the same as in the solution above, and then I added a barrier to avoid that processes those are not on turn run always in circle and check their number. It made non-sense. Now when you are not on turn, you have to wait in "waiting room", and when someone enters doctors room with his number (it means it is his turn), he signals all guys waiting in waiting room (barrier), and they go to check if they are on turn. This second semaphore made it a lot faster. Mostly the code is same as above.